# Authentication for query APIs for Amazon Managed Prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, promql

I am currently experimenting Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus. I am trying to setup some querying via the HTTP APIs that prometheus has. Their documentation mentions that I can use the usual prometheus APIs but it makes no mention about the authentication needed for the APIs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-stats.html

Given that the setup needs IAM roles configured, what headers/params do we need to send as part of the auth piece to make successful queries to this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Your question: *...given that the setup needs IAM roles configured, what headers/params do we need to send as part of the auth piece to make successful queries to this ?..*

Please list your code snippet on what you've tried, its really hard to answer in the blind on whats wrong.

---

> ## Step 1: `Double check` if you have `configured` the following correctly

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17", // correct date
 "Statement": [
  {
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": [
 "aps: CreateAlertManagerDefinition",
 "aps: DescribeAlertManagerSilence",
 "aps: DescribeAlertManagerDefinition",
 "aps: PutAlertManagerDefinition",
 "aps: DeleteAlertManagerDefinition",
 "aps: ListAlerts",
 "aps: ListRules",
 "aps: ListAlertManagerReceivers",
 "aps: ListAlertManagerSilences",
 "aps: ListAlertManagerAlerts",
 "aps: ListAlertManagerAlertGroups",
 "aps: GetAlertManagerStatus",
 "aps: GetAlertManagerSilence",
 "aps: ListAlertManagerSilences",
 "aps: PutAlertManagerSilences",
 "aps: DeleteAlertManagerSilence",
 "aps: CreateAlertManagerAlerts"
 ],
 "Resource": "*"
  }
 ]
}
```

---

From some older notes based on V4.

> ### Code Example `HTTPS request header components`, Prometheus *V4*

```
GET https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08 HTTP/1.1
Host: iam.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-Amz-Date: 20150830T123600Z
```

To create the string to sign

Start with the algorithm designation, followed by a newline character. This value is the hashing algorithm that you use to calculate the digests in the canonical request. For SHA256, AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 is the algorithm.

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
```

Append the request date value, followed by a newline character. The date is specified with ISO8601 basic format in the `x-amz-date header in the format YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'`. This value must match the value you used in any previous steps.

```
20150830T123600Z
```

Append the credential scope value, followed by a newline character. This value is a string that includes the date, the Region you are targeting, the service you are requesting, and a termination string ("`aws4_request`") in lowercase characters. The Region and service name strings must be UTF-8 encoded.

```
20190830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request
```

The date must be in the `YYYYMMDD` format. Note that the date does not include a time value.

Verify that the Region you specify is the Region that you are sending the request to.

Append the hash of the canonical request that you created in Task 1: Create a canonical request for Signature Version 4. This value is not followed by a newline character. The hashed canonical request must be lowercase base-16 encoded, as defined by Section 8 of RFC 4648.

```
f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59
```

The following string to sign is a request to IAM on August 30, 2019.

- **Example string to sign**

  AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
  20190830T123600Z
  20190830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request
  f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59